# Codeigniter install on windows server

Tags: codeigniter, iis, windows-server-2012

I was wondering if it is possible to install and run my Codeigniter application on a windows server? I have read that windows server doesn't use .htaccess but web.config.

Does anyone know if it is possible or is there a guide to test with?

I have tried searching but nothing has come up so far.

Comment: what ? there is a difference between windows-server and IIS ... you can easily install apache / php on windows server 2012 - and if you don't want to, simply configure iis properly (maybe https://gist.github.com/wmandai/d28cc45f10a19eec0fcb will help you)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with either. I am assuming windows server. Is there a guide to do that? I am confused on how I can use the link you gave me. Is {REQUEST_FILENAME} supposed to be the path of my htaccess file?